# Maven project Jenkins build not success.

Tags: git, maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build my Maven TestNG selenium project via Jenkins through git repository. When i'm click on build option there is error written in log as

"A Maven installation needs to be available for this project to be built.Either your server has no Maven installations defined, or the requested Maven version does not exist."

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Sorry but you need to install Maven on your Jenkins as the error message already states.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Maven on your server and to setup Maven in Jenkins.

Go to:

```
Manage Jenkins->Configure System
```

Scroll to the Maven section and click the button `Add Maven`.

More details in this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_maven_setup.htm).